# Trouble concatenating two appended arrays

Tags: python

I'm having trouble combining two arrays I want to be able to print out together. I want one "account" of each to correspond with one "customer" but I do not know how to do this. The program takes in values from two account files into one array, and one customer file into one array.

```
def __init__(self) -> None:
        #1st list (array) to store CAccount and SAccount classess
        self._accounts = []
        #2nd list (array) to store Customer objects
        self._customers = [] #2

    def main(self) -> None: #c)
        try:
            # Reading the data from CAccounts.txt file to create objects of the CAccount class inside the 1st list (array).
            for txt in (CACCOUNTS_TXT, SACCOUNTS_TXT):
                obj = CAccount if txt == CACCOUNTS_TXT else SAccount #1)d)e)
                path = os.path.join(CURR_DIR, txt)
                # Reading txt file
                with open(path) as f:
                    for row in f:
                        # Parsing file data
                        data = row.strip().split(";")
                        accNo = int(data[0])
                        accType = data[1]
                        bal = float(data[2])
                        # Handling optional parameter
                        if len(data) > 3:
                            amt = float(data[3])
                            account = obj(accNo, accType, bal, amt)
                        else:
                            account = obj(accNo, accType, bal)
                        self._accounts.append(account)

            # Reading the data from Customers.txt file to create objects of the Customer class inside the 2nd list (array).
            path = os.path.join(CURR_DIR, CUSTOMERS_TXT)
            with open(path) as f:
                for row in f:
                    # Parsing file data
                    data = row.strip().split(";")
                    custNo = int(data[0])
                    custNm = data[1]
                    age = int(data[2])
                    city = data[3]
                    customer = Customer(
                        custNo, custNm, age, city,
                        self._accounts[len(self._customers)])
                    self._customers.append(customer)`

for i in self._customers:
            print(customer)

        for i in self._accounts:
            print(account)
```

So instead of:

```
Account no. 246805:
Type: Saving
Balance: 1500.0
Maximum transaction amount: 4000.0
```

and

```
Customer no. 586425
Name: Tony
Age: 41
City: Hobart
```

To be printed seperately, I'd like them to be combined together like:

```
Customer no. 586425
        Name: Tony
        Age: 41
        City: Hobart
        Account no. 246805:
        Type: Saving
        Balance: 1500.0
        Maximum transaction amount: 4000.0
```

I've tried just combining the two via +, I've tried combining the txt sections into one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to combine two lists pairwise:

```
for customer, account in zip(self._customers, self._accounts):
    print(customer)
    print(account)
```

This is equivalent to iterating over both lists simultaneously by using the same index for each:

```
for i in range(min(len(self._customers), len(self._accounts))):
    print(self._customers[i])
    print(self._accounts[i])
```

or using two iterators and continuing until one or the other is exhausted:

```
customers = iter(self._customers)
accounts = iter(self._accounts)
while True:
    try:
        customer = next(customers)
        account = next(accounts)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(customer)
    print(account)
```